# How to properly union date and time in datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please advise how to do the following:

> You need to take a date from one column and join it with the time of
> another column, and then add one day to the received date.

I wrote such a query, but on some data it gives a conversion error. Please tell me a more optimal query so that it always works when combining the date and time format into datetime.

```
create table dt (date1 datetime, date2 datetime)

insert into dt values('19000101 17:17:00.000','19070101 17:51:00.000')
insert into dt values('19000101 18:20:00.000','19080101 18:21:00.000')
insert into dt values('20000101 06:00:00.000','20100101 06:40:00.000')


select 
dateadd(dd,1,convert(datetime,convert(date,date1))+ convert(datetime,convert(time, date2)))
from dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where such an error could occur:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
    Duration TIME,
    AdditionalDelay SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Example (Duration, AdditionalDelay)
VALUES ('00:01:02',3)

SELECT Duration+AdditionalDelay FROM dbo.Example
```

To fix this, you need to identify the proper unit of measure for `AdditionalDelay` and use `DATEADD` instead of `+`. For example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,AdditionalDelay,Duration) FROM dbo.Example
```